# O terceiro parâmetro do filter_input é obrigatório no PHP?

Tags: php

```
$nome = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

eu dei uma olhada no manual do PHP mas não diz nada, vi um cara não usando o terceiro parâmetro e daí fiquei na dúvida se é obrigatório ou não

Answer (score 2):

A [documentação](http://php.net/filter_input) da função `filter_input` diz o seguinte sobre o terceiro parâmetro:

> "If omitted, FILTER_DEFAULT will be used, which is equivalent to FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW. This will result in no filtering taking place by default."

Ou seja, o terceiro parâmetro não é obrigatório e pode ser omitido. Apesar disso não filtrar o valor de fato.

Answer (score 2):

Não é, veja como esta na documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

```
mixed filter_input ( int $type , string $variable_name [, int $filter = FILTER_DEFAULT [, mixed $options ]] )
```

Esses `[...]` indicam argumentos opcionais, em PHP existe argumentos pré-definidos, quando você omite no teu uso o php passa o valor padrão, que no caso especifico desta função seria o `FILTER_DEFAULT`, o código que você postou mostra que a pessoa trocou `FILTER_DEFAULT` por `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`, ou seja, cada um deles serve para uma coisa, basta ver os valores suportados em http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

como diz na doc:

> If omitted, `FILTER_DEFAULT` will be used, which is equivalent to `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW`. This will result in no filtering taking place by default.
>
> Se omitido irá usar `FILTER_DEFAULT`, que é equivalente ao `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW`. Isto irá resultar em um valor não filtrado.

Só pra constar, o `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` faz parte do http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php, este filtro no caso escapa/converte caracteres como: `<`, `>`, `&`, dentre outros que o valor ASCII seja menor que 32, ou seja, algo como:

```
<?php
$str = "< > & \0 \n \r";

$x = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

var_dump($x);
```

Irá imprimir isto:

```
string(34) "&#60; &#62; &#38; &#0; &#10; &#13;"
```

Que são entidades HTML, que quando renderizadas na página exibem de fato `< > & \0 \n \r`, mas sem afetar o HTML.